# Getting error "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testm.php on line 5" while executing Mysql command

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my code. I dont know what the problem is and where i am going wrong.  the error says "Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\testm.php on line 5"

```
<?php

$mysqli = NEW MySQLi('localhost','root','','test');
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM project ORDERBY Id ASC");
if($resultSet->num_rows!=0)
{



    while($rows = $resultSet->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $Id = $rows['Id'];
        $ScholarNumber= $rows['ScholarNumber'];
        $Name = $rows['rows'];

        echo "Id: $Id<br/> $ScholarNumber <br/> $name<br/><br/>";

    }
}
    else{
        echo "Error";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently your `$resultSet` is `FALSE` (that happens when there is no result), which is not an object.
And it is `FALSE` because you have bug in your query, ORDER BY should be written separately:

Change

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM project ORDERBY Id ASC");
                                                       ^^
```

to

```
$resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM project ORDER BY Id ASC");
                                                       ^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Query:

```
 $resultSet = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM project ORDER BY Id ASC");
```